# How to Implement Turtle in Skulpt (in Meteor)?

Tags: python, meteor

My code pretty much matches what's provided on [Skulpt.org](http://skulpt.org) yet I can't seem to get any Turtles to appear on my canvas. I added code to ensure that the turtle library is being loaded and that the python is being run successfully. Both messages say that this is the case; everything seems to be working as it should.

Here's some of my template code:

```
Template.pythonEnv.events({
'click #py_run': function(event, template) {
    // get content from Ace
    Tracker.autorun(function (e) {
        var editorPy = AceEditor.instance("py_inPanel", {
            theme:"dawn",
            mode:"python"
        });
        if(editorPy.loaded === true){
            e.stop();
            Session.set("pyContent", editorPy.getValue());
        }
    });
    // Skulpt
    var prog =  Session.get("pyContent");
    var mypre = document.getElementById("py_outputPanel");
    mypre.innerHTML = '';

    Sk.onAfterImport = function(library) {
        switch(library) {
            case 'turtle':
                console.log('turtle loaded');  // *** CHECK TO SEE IF TURTLE LOADED ***
                break;
        }
    }

    Sk.pre = "py_outputPanel"; // output
    Sk.configure({
        inputfun: function(prompt) {
            return window.prompt(prompt); // for raw_input()
        },
        inputfunTakesPrompt: true,
        output: outf,
        read: builtinRead
    });
    (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'py_turtlePanel';
    var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
        return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
    });
    myPromise.then(function(mod) {
        console.log('Python - success'); // *** CHECK TO SEE IF PYTHON RAN ***
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
    });
    // resize output panel
    template.$(".py_panel").height($(window).height() - template.$("#py_header").height() - 90);
},
...
```

And here's my html code:

```
<template name="pythonEnv">
{{#with file}}
    <div id="py_container">
        <div id="py_header">
            <div id="py_buttonContainer">
                <p id="py_toggle_note">Click to toggle: &nbsp; </p>
                <div class="py_toggleButton py_active" id="py_in">Python</div>
                <div class="py_toggleButton py_active" id="py_output">Output</div>
                <div class="py_toggleButton" id="py_turtle">Turtle</div>
            </div>
            <button class="login" id="py_run">Run!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="py_bodyContainer">
            <pre id="py_inPanel" class="py_input py_panel"></pre>
            <pre id="py_outputPanel" class="py_panel"></pre>
            <canvas id="py_turtlePanel" class="py_panel py_hidden"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/with}}
</template>
```

**Amendment:**
I added this code under my `'click #py_run'` function:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("py_turtlePanel");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
context.fillText("Zibri", (canvas.width / 2) - 17, (canvas.height / 2) + 8);
```

And it works! But my turtle still doesn't load. I tried running the following turtle code:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

for c in ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']:
    t.color(c)
    t.forward(75)
    t.left(90)
```

Without any luck. Also, everything with my Skulpt-Python functionality seems to be working properly as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you output other things to your canvas? Does the python interpreter work otherwise? Are there other packages you can try to load?

Comment: @Mikkel just updated my post for you

Comment: @Mikkel and to your point, I tried importing numpy and pygal as a client and I received: `ImportError: No module named numpy on line 10` both times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the issue is that I read the initial code given on http://www.skulpt.org/# wrong. Instead of putting my turtle code in a `<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>` I should instead put it in a `<div id="mycanvas"></div>`.